# Conicoid (3-D): feet of the six normals drawn from a point to the conicoid and finding of plane.

Tags: geometry

If P, Q and R and P', Q' and R' are feet of the six normals drawn from a point to the conicoid 3x^2+ 2y^2+ z^2=6 and the plane PQR is 3x+2y+z=6 then find plane P'Q'R'.

Comment: Here,  consider a point  (a, b, c) from which six normals are drawn to the given conicoid.

Comment: That plane looks tangent to the quadric at $(1,1,1)$.